# Find statement question and the difference between the path for the node and depthFirst() when parsing the XML

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I have a following xml structure:

```
def xml = """
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <field1>DC40</field1>
            <field2>200</field2>
            <field3>0000000000011620</field3>
        </c>
    </b>
    <d>
            <field4>C40</field4>
    </d>
</a>
"""
```

and I want to find the value from the  segment and want to do it further down the road from the list with collect, so I wrote the following code as a PoC on how I will approach this task:

```
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def selectedField = 'field3' 

def result = rootNode.depthFirst().find { it.name() == selectedField }?.text()
def result2 = rootNode.a.b.field3.text()
def result3 = rootNode.a.b.find { it.name() == selectedField }?.text()
println "$selectedField: $result"
println "$selectedField: $result2"
println "$selectedField: $result3"
```

The problem is that the first two results work properly and return the value of the node (0000000000011620), however the result3 is always empty and I have no idea why. Could someone explain to me how is the following statement incorrect?
rootNode.a.b.find { it.name() == selectedField }?.text()
I would also prefer to point directly in which part of the xml structure it should look up the value and avoid using '**' or depthFirst().

All 3 results should be the same.